# Save int into nullable int column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save an integer into a nullable int column only if there is a value

```
if (user.AssociationID != 0)
{
   int? AssociationID = user.AssociationID;
   currentUser.AssociationID == AssociationID;
}
```

I have tried casing currentUser into an int `(int?)currentUser.AssociationID`

I know this has to be terribly simple.  I've googled for the title of the question and am not finding the results I need.  Be nice, I'm a noob.

**Error I'm getting:**
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
currentUser.AssociationID == AssociationID;
```

should be

```
currentUser.AssociationID = AssociationID;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (user.AssociationID != null)
{
   int? AssociationID = user.AssociationID;
   currentUser.AssociationID = AssociationID;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use .HasValue & Value.

```
if (user.AssociationID.HasValue)
{
   currentUser.AssociationID = user.AssociationID.Value;
}
```

Comment: `user.AssociationID` is not nullable; it's just an `int`.